# (Node.js/mocha/chai) Sending parameters in request object in a HTTP POST

Tags: node.js, http, express, mocha.js, sinon

I'm trying to test someone else's POST route (using mocha/chai/sinon) and I'm running into a wall.  Here's what works so far:  Most of the information grabbed in the post route is retrieved from req.body as illustrated in this snippet.

```
  var participants = JSON.parse(req.body.participantList);
  var scenarioId = req.body.scenarioId;
```

I'm able to send up these variables using the test code below because .send() places parameters into the body.

```
chai.request(server)
  .post('/viewer/add-exercise-participants')
  .send({"scenarioId": 9999, "user": {"id": 1234}, 'participantList': '['
      + '{"user_id": 1111, "role_id": [4444]},'
      + '{"user_id": 2222, "role_id": [1111]},'
      + '{"user_id": 4444, "role_id": [3333, 4444]}'
    + ']'
  })
  .end(function(err, res){
    console.log(res.body);
    done();
  });
```

So just to be clear, what I have above is working so far.  Here is where I run into issue.   Later down within the same route, they want a req.user.id which is throwing me off.  Since req.user.id is not inside of body I don't know how to send that with my HTTP POST request.

```
var requserid = req.user.id;
```

How do I set this req.user.id variable when I call make a request to this route? The project is in node.js and I'm testing unit testing using the mocha/chai/sinon packages.

Here is an example of how the route is called somewhere else in the project.

```
  $.post('/viewer/add-exercise-participants', {
  scenarioId: scenarioId,
  participantList: JSON.stringify(selected_users)
}).done(function(data) {
  noty({
    layout: 'topCenter',
    text: data,
    theme: 'relax',
    type: 'alert',
    timeout: 3000,
    animation: {
      open: {
        height: 'toggle'
      },
      close: {
        height: 'toggle'
      },
      easing: 'swing',
      speed: 500
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: How could we possibly know?  There's no server code here, so who knows how data is getting attached to `req`.  If this is in the query string or part of the path, you'll have to add that to the URL in your `.post()` line.

Comment: I edited the original post to include an example of how it is called somewhere else.  I dug around throughout the project and still can't find out how user.id gets attached to the request object.

Comment: Still not sure how we can help you, without knowing what's in `selected_users` then.  Somewhere in that code, `req.user` is getting set.  Probably through some middleware.

Comment: I have no problem setting that participant list (I do this in my .send in the first snippet) because participant list lies in the body.  The issue is req.user is not in the body (if it was req.body.user then I would know how to set it) and I agree with you it's probably some kind of middleware.  I've been digging through all the files but I'm having no luck.  

Here's some more information I found if this helps.  When console logging the request object in the routes file, I found this:
  locals: { user: undefined },
I'm not sure if this will help at all.  Maybe I could mock this somehow?

Comment: It's probably tied up with an authentication header or cookie or something.